# this.setState is not a function for textfield

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Trying to do validations on a textfield while the user is typing in a text field. I want to change the state of the `errorText` attribute on the fly.

I receive the error `Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function` when trying to set the state. Relevant code below.

```
export default class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            username: null,
            errorCopy: null
        };
    }
    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({errorCopy: 'Generic error copy'});
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <TextField
                hintText="Username"
                value={this.state.username}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                errorText={this.state.errorCopy} />
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoops, in ES6 class binding has to be done manually.

Needed to add `.bind(this)` to the handleChange

```
export default class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            username: null,
            errorCopy: null
        };
    }
    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({errorCopy: 'Generic error copy'});
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <TextField
                hintText="Username"
                value={this.state.username}
                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                errorText={this.state.errorCopy} />
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be bound manually, you can do `handleChange = (e) => {}` as well but yes, the auto binding feature is removed.

Comment: Doing `handleChange = (e) => {` gave me an unexpected token on the first equal sign. Using babel & webpack.

Comment: Which stage of babel do you use?

Comment: Using babel-loader 5.3.2 that uses babel-core 5.4.0

Comment: You can even give like `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)` in the constructor